# Match regular expression specific character quantities in any order

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need to match a series of strings that:

- Contain at least 3 numbers
- 0 or more letters
- 0 or 1 `-` (not more)
- 0 or 1 `\` (not more)

These characters can be in any position in the string.

The regular expression I have so far is:

`([A-Z0-9]*[0-9]{3,}[\/]?[\-]?[0-9]*[A-Z]*)`

This matches the following data in the following cases. The only one that does not match is the first one:

```
02ABU-D9435
013DFC
1123451
03323456782
ADS7124536768
03SDFA9433/0
03SDFA9433/
03SDFA9433/1
A41B03423523
O4AGFC4430
```

[image: Regex matches]

I think perhaps I am being too prescriptive about positioning. How can I update this regex to match all possibilities?

PHP PCRE

The following would not match:

```
01/01/2018 [multiple / or -]
AA-AA   [no numbers]
```

Thanks

Comment: @Andreas I put it right there, please see question again :)

Comment: Sorry missed it

Answer (score 0):

One option could be using lookaheads to assert 3 digits, not 2 backslashes and not 2 times a hyphen.

```
(?<!\S)(?=(?:[^\d\s]*\d){3})(?!(?:[^\s-]*-){2})(?!(?:[^\s\\]*\\){2})[A-Z0-9/\\-]+(?!\S)
```

**About the pattern**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `(?=(?:[^\d\s]*\d){3})` Assert wat is on the right is 3 times a whitespace char or digit
- `(?!(?:[^\s-]*-){2})` Assert what is on the right is not 2 times a whitespace char a hyphen
- `(?!(?:[^\s\\]*\\){2})` Assert what is on the right is not 2 times a whitespace char a backslash
- `[A-Z0-9/\\-]+` Match any of the listed 1+ times
- `(?!\S)` Assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QJj6Eh/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, you are right, I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Your patterns can be checked with positive/negative lookaheads anchored at the start of the string:

- at least 3 digits -> find (not necessarily consecutive) 3 digits
- no more than 1 '-' -> assert absence of (not necessarily consecutive) 2 '-' characters
- no more than 1 '/' -> assert absence of (not necessarily consecutive) 2 '/' characters
- 0 or more letters -> no check needed.

If these conditions are met, any content is permitted.

The regex implementing this:

```
^(?=(([^0-9\r\n]*\d){3}))(?!(.*-){2})(?!(.*\/){2}).*$
```

Check out [this Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/LgQwUK/3).

**Remark**

This solution assumes that each string tested resides on its own line, ie. not just being separated by whitespace.
In case the strings are separated by whitespace, choose the [solution of user @TheFourthBird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57110546/588916) (which essentially is the same as this one but caters for the whitespace separation)

Answer (score 0):

You can test the condition for both the hyphen and the slash into a same lookahead using a capture group and a backreference:

```
~\A(?!.*([-/]).*\1)(?:[A-Z/-]*\d){3,}[A-Z/-]*\z~
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/njw3j8/1)

detailled:

```
~ # using the tild as pattern delimiter avoids to escape all slashes in the pattern
\A # start of the string
(?! .* ([-/]) .* \1 ) # negative lookahead:
                        #  check that there's no more than one hyphen and one slash

(?: [A-Z/-]* \d ){3,} # at least 3 digits

[A-Z/-]* # eventual other characters until the end of the string
\z # end of the string.
~
```

To better understand (if you are not familiar with): these three subpatterns start from the same position (in this case the beginning of the string):

```
\A
(?! .* ([-/]) .* \1 )
(?: [A-Z/-]* \d ){3,}
```

This is possible only because the two first are *zero-width assertions* that are simple tests and don't consume any character.